# How to display service-name prefix to all metrics in Kamon(1.x) Datadog dashboard

Tags: akka, datadog, kamon, akka-monitoring

I am using Kamon DatadogAgentReporter to record different metrics in my application. After migrating Kamon from 0.6.x to 1.x, I can see only the list of metrics with tags without any service name. I added the reporter like this, Kamon.addReporter(new DatadogAgentReporter()) and the config as given below,

```
kamon {

    environment {
        service = "xxx" //application-name
        host = ""
        instance = ""
    }

    util.filters {
        datadog - tag - filter {
            includes = ["**"]
            excludes = []
        }
    }

    datadog {
        additional - tags {
            service = "yes"
            host = "yes"
            instance = "yes"
            blacklisted - tags = []
        }

        filter - config - key = "datadog-tag-filter"
    }
}
```

Did I miss something? How do I get the display service-name prefix for my metrices?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an intentional "feature" https://github.com/kamon-io/kamon-datadog/issues/19 introduced in 1.x. They have chosen approach to put service name in tag instead.